# Why Dot product of my vectors takes longer than usual?

Tags: timing

I have a list containing 100 complex numbers lying between 1.9 + 1.9 i and 2.0 + 2.0 i
you can download its mx file from the link below and import it in Mathematica:

http://adambarfib.ir1.rapidpars.com/17830/18651983/s4fkhv5c31j/vec.mx

Now if you perform a simple calculation with this imported list:

```
vec = Import["vec.mx"];
c = Table[1.0 + 2.0 I + n (0.01 - 0.01 I), {n, 1, 100}];
AbsoluteTiming[Do[vec.c, 1000]]
```

It takes 0.0070265 seconds on my laptop.
but a similar calculation with a randomly created list, takes half time:

```
randomVec = RandomComplex[{1.9 + 1.9 I, 2.0 + 2.0 I}, 100];
AbsoluteTiming[Do[randomVec.c, 1000]]
```

This one takes 0.0036907 seconds.

Could anyone help me what is the problem with my `vec`?

Comment: Very strange, I observe the contrary. MMA12.1 on Windows 10. I increased the loop to 100'000 and get nearly 10 times faster evaluation time with your data:AbsoluteTiming[Do[vec.c, 100000]] -> {0.017462, Null},  AbsoluteTiming[Do[randomVec.c, 100000]] -> {0.140501, Null} If I may speculate, perhaps you data has some structure that can be exploited?

Comment: Please keep in mind that .mx is not a good format for sharing data. There's no guarantee that someone else can import it, since it's a system-dependent format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vec` array is not packed, search questions related to `PackedArray`

```
vec = Import["vec.mx"];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[vec]
c = Table[1.0 + 2.0 I + n (0.01 - 0.01 I), {n, 1, 100}];
RepeatedTiming[Do[vec.c, 1000]]

vec = Developer`ToPackedArray[vec] ;
Developer`PackedArrayQ[vec]
c = Table[1.0 + 2.0 I + n (0.01 - 0.01 I), {n, 1, 100}];
RepeatedTiming[Do[vec.c, 1000]]
(* False *)
(* {0.0038056587301587307`3.,Null} *)
(* True *)
(* \
{0.002334895238095238`2.,Null} *)
```